ManytoMany fields generating "no such table:<tablename>" error where <tablename> is related to no model in models.py
I'm sorry if question title is confusing or not clear but i didn't have a better way of writting it.
I have a django app root, in models.py i created a model Post containing 3 manytomany fields ; File, Video and Picture and some other fields and while trying to populate the model in Django Admin or even to view any of the created Posts i get this error message django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: root_post_Picture. I already ran python manage.py sqlmigrate root 0001_initial and saw no table with such name and it's not surprising since root_post_Picture corresponds to none of my models . I think it is related to the manaytomanyfields i created since the name root_post_Picture seems to be a combination of the tables root_post and root_picture from my database.
views.py
def postcreation(request):
    Videoarray=[]
    Picturearray=[]
    Filearray=[]
    form=AbsolutePostForm(request.GET)
    file = Fileform(request.FILES)
    pic = PictureForm(request.FILES)
    vid = VideoForm(request.FILES)
    if request.method=="POST":
        file = Fileform(request.FILES)
        if "File" in request.POST:
            if file.is_valid():
                File=Files(Post_type="posts",Post_id=get_id_generation("postids.txt"),File=request.FILES["File"])
                File.save()
                Filearray.append(File)
                print("file")
                return HttpResponse("file")
        pic = PictureForm(request.FILES)
        if "Picture" in request.FILES:
            if pic.is_valid():
                Picture = Pictures(Post_type="posts", Post_id=get_id_generation("postids.txt"),Picture=request.FILES["Picture"])
                Picture.save()
                Picturearray.append(Picture)
                print("pic")
                return HttpResponse("picture")
        vid = VideoForm(request.FILES)
        if "Video" in request.FILES:
            if vid.is_valid():
                Video = Videos(Post_type="posts", Post_id=get_id_generation("postids.txt"),Video=request.FILES["Video"])
                Video.save()
                print("vid")
                Videoarray.append(Video)
        if "Postcoment" in request.POST:
            form = AbsolutePostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post=form.cleaned_data["Postcoment"]
                Main=Post(post=post)
                Main.save()
                for obj in Filearray:
                    Main.File.add(obj)
                for obj in Videoarray:
                    Main.File.add(obj)
                for obj in Picturearray:
                    Main.File.add(obj)
                return HttpResponse("welldone")
    context={"form":form,"pic": pic,"file":file,"vid":vid}
    return render(request,"postcreationpage.html",context)

models.py
class Pictures(models.Model):
    Post_id=models.IntegerField()
    Post_type=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/posts")
class Files(models.Model):
    Post_id = models.IntegerField()
    Post_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    File = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/posts",validators=[documentvalidator])
class Videos(models.Model):
    Post_id = models.IntegerField()
    Post_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos/posts",validators=[videovalidator])
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    Picture=models.ManyToManyField(Pictures, blank=True)
    File = models.ManyToManyField(Files, blank=True)
    Video = models.ManyToManyField(Videos, blank=True)
    likes=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    coments = models.IntegerField(default=0)

in template
<div class="panel">
            <div class="seperate">
                <div class="attachements">
                    <div style="position: relative;">
                        <div style="width:40px; 
                                    height: 35px; ">
                                        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{ pic }}
                                            <button type="submit" class="submiters">sauvegarder l'image choisie</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                        <img src="{% static 'im.png' %}" class="pinner">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: relative;">
                        <div style="
                                    width:40px; 
                                    height: 35px; ">
                                        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{ vid }}
                                            <button type="submit" class="submiters" style="top: 100px;">sauvegarder la video choisie</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                        <img src="{% static 'vid.png' %}" class="pinner">
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: relative;">
                        <div style="
                                    width:40px; 
                                    height: 35px; ">
                                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        {{ file }}
                                        <button type="submit" class="submiters" style="top: 150px;">sauvegarder le document choisi</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                        <img src="{% static 'doc.png' %}" class="pinner">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit">POSTER</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

forms.py
class AbsolutePostForm(forms.Form):
    Postcoment=forms.CharField(label="",required=False,max_length=700, widget=(forms.Textarea(attrs={"required": "True",'rows':"30", 'cols':"60", 'class':"postgrid", 'placeholder':"DECRIVEZ VOTRE POSTE"})))
class Fileform(forms.Form):
    File = forms.FileField(label="",required=False,widget=(forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":"invisible"})), validators=[documentvalidator])
class PictureForm(forms.Form):
    Picture = forms.ImageField(label="",required=False,widget=(forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":"invisible"})))
class VideoForm(forms.Form):
    Video = forms.FileField(label="",required=False,widget=(forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":"invisible"})),validators=[videovalidator])


Did you run python manage.py migrate?  With a ManyToManyField Django will indeed  create an intermediate table, using the name of the ManyToManyField as well as the name of the model that contains that field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/models/fields/#id1).  python manage.py makemigrations creates the file that will generate the SQL and sqlmigrate will, I believe print out, but not generate the tables in your database.

Yes I ran both makemigrations and migrate
